# Add URl to cookie and redirect to URL on return

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I need to check if a cookie is present in order to let a user continue on their journey, if it's not they click a button (which then sets the cookie) and fires them off to a third party to register some details before returning.

I can set and check for the cookie but I'd like to add the page url to the cookie and when the user returns from the third party site the url in the cookie is picked up and they're redirected to the page they left from. (Hope that all makes sense).

Code so far...

```
//Check for cookie

if (document.cookie.indexOf("LostForWordsSession=Valid") == -1) {
    $('.poster-image').show(); // This is a button that's shown if the cookie isn't present
}

// Button code

var url = window.location.href; 

$(".poster-image").click(function(){
    document.cookie = "LostForWordsSession=Valid; path=url";
    window.location.replace("off to another site to register");
});
```

Once the user has registered they will be forwarded to a generic page on my site from where I'd like to redirect them (no code for that yet as I'm a bit stumped).

Any help really appreciated! And thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for sessionStorage:

```js
// I assume you want to go to the old URL?
// this code needs to be in all pages you can return to from rd party
const url = window.location.href; 
const session = sessionStorage.getItem("LostForWordsSessionUrl");

if (session && session != url) location.replace(session); 
else session = false;
$('.poster-image').toggle(!session); // show if no session

$(".poster-image").on("click",function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem("LostForWordsSessionUrl",url)
    window.location.replace("off to another site to register");
});
```

Comment: Does a seesion end when the browser is closed? I need this to last so a user doesn't have to re-register at any point.

Comment: Just change the word sessionStorage to localStorage